# Is it possible to rename the device in Fiware?

Tags: iot, fiware, fiware-orion

I have registered a device under

```
"device_id": "Sens1",         
"entity_name": "Dim",          
"entity_type": "Sensor"
```

Is it possible to change the entity_name to something different? Or I will have to delete this device and register a new one? Was searching for that in tutorials, but have found information only about attributes's change.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not fully sure and I may be wrong... but I think it is not possible. However, you can delete and create again, which is has the same effect in the IOTA API.

This is different to the Orion Context Broker API (NGSIv2) which allows modifications on the entities or attributes without needed to delete + create.

Comment: I neither meant attributes not entities. I meant exactly the device name, which is kind of serves like a base for all the entities and attributes (in v2 we would put the name of it to retrieve all entities, for example). Looks like yea, the only way is to delete and register again.

Thanks!